# Regex not including any character at the beginning of line, only comments

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to remove any comments from C++ source file with regular expressions.

Here is an example of the code:

```
std::regex single_regex("(//.*)");
std::regex multi_regex("/\\*.*?");
std::regex multi_close_regex("\\*/");
```

and here is the example code:

```
/* multi line
comment 
*/

//single line comment
some code
//another single line comment
some other code //comment
```

and here is the code where I do the iteration:

```
 void CommentStrip::GetLines(const std::string &line, size_t &single_comm, size_t &multi_comm, const std::string &language, bool &flag)
    {
        if (language == "C" || language == "C++" || language == "C/C++ Header") {

            std::regex single_regex("(//.*)");
            std::regex multi_regex("/\\*.*?");
            std::regex multi_close_regex("\\*/");

            std::string tmp_line;

            if (!line.empty()) {
                if (std::regex_search(line,single_regex))
                    single_comm++;
                if(std::regex_search(line,multi_regex))
                    flag = true;
                if(flag)
                    multi_comm++;
                if(std::regex_search(line, multi_close_regex) && flag == true)
                    flag = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the current regex counts the last line as the comment, e.g. (some other code `//` comment), but I don't want to!

is there any way to modify my regex so that it will ignore any line of code that not start as the comment ( `//` or `/* .. */`)?

Comment: You have to post the code where you do actual iteration.

Comment: Yes sorry i will edited now

Answer (score 0):

Modify your regex to `std::regex single_regex("(^//.*)");` so that it will search for `"//"` in the beginning of line

Comment: And how i should to do this? can you give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

To find the comment only in starting of the line, you can use ^.